# mouseover event on overlapping css grid objects with surrounding empty cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

this seemed like a simple idea, but is proving to be overly complicated. I'm attempting to have two overlapping grid objects, one on top of the other in a fixed position. I want to register mouseover events on the non-empty cells in either of the overlapping grids.

In this example I have two overlapping grids. However, the mouseevent only fires for the uppermost grid element, even though there are empty cells. So, for example if I place my cursor on the red square no mouseevent fires, but for the blue square it does fire.

Any ideas or workarounds for how to solve this. Thanks!

```js
$(".elem1").mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("elem1");
})

$(".elem2").mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("elem2");
})
```

```css
.container1 {
    position:fixed;

    display: grid;

    width: 100%;

    grid-template-columns: 20px 100px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
    grid-template-areas: ". elem1 .";
}

.container2 {
    position:fixed;

    display: grid;

    width: 100%;

    grid-template-columns: 50px 100px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:100px;
    grid-template-areas: ". elem2 .";
}

.elem1 {
    background-color: red;
    grid-area: elem1;
}

.elem2 {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-area: elem2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1"><div class="elem1"></div></div>
<div class="container2"><div class="elem2"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though parts of the top grid are visually empty, they still receive mouse events and get in the way of things behind it.

You can do:

```
.container2 { pointer-events: none }
.elem2 { pointer-events: visible }
```

to make the empty parts of `.container2` unclickable, while `.elem2` remains clickable. This won't work in IE.

Comment: You would have to actually get `container2` out of the way for real. In your example `.container2 { height: 0 }` works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you wanted to achieve, but as you recognized - one div were overlapping another one, so there were no possibility for event ti fire, instead i would suggest you to put both divs in a single grid and overlap one with another by using negative margins.

https://jsfiddle.net/awv8evs3/4/

`<div class="container"><div class="elem1"></div><div class="elem2"></div></div>`

```
.container {
    position:fixed;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
}

.elem1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.elem2 {
  margin-left:-60px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm more interested in implementing complicated layouts but in discrete overlapping grids, instead of a single grid with messy margin declarations.

Comment: complicated layouts arent messy at all. Besides, why do you want them to overlap?